# Re-sizing problems in HighChart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

When the page loads, the featured charts that are present in the page does not take up the available width and overflows their columns. However, when the window is re-sized or I try to investigate using Inspect element, the charts immediately snap into the correct dimensions. This behavior occurs in Chrome, FF, and IE.

I have tried the following with no results :-(

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;margin: 0 auto"></div>
$(window).resize();
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Could you post your example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and I "fixed" the issue by delaying the creation of the chart:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(element).highcharts({...});
}, 0);
```

More details there: [Highcharts dynamic (re-)sizing in AngularJS tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414507/highcharts-dynamic-re-sizing-in-angularjs-tabs)