# Highcharts dynamic (re-)sizing in AngularJS tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

My application displays HighCharts charts in various tabs (using AngularJS). Note that the charts are re-generated on the fly **every time a tab is selected** (Meaning that Angular "removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree" every time).

My problem is that the size of the chart is correct *only the first time* I click on a tab. When I switch tabs, the charts that are created largely exceed the size of their container. Surprisingly, the charts are correctly resized after a window resize (i.e. when `chart.reflow()` is called).

So I tried the following, which did not help:

```
$(element).highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy',
      events: {
        load: function () {
          this.reflow();
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

Finally, the following did work, but it feels like a hack.

```
$(element).highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'scatter',
      zoomType: 'xy',
      events: {
        load: function () {
          var chart = this;
          setTimeout(function () { chart.reflow(); }, 0);
        }
      }
    },
    ...
```

Any idea where the problem comes from? I am spending hours on this, and this is pretty frustrating...

EDIT: I have another related question: By default my charts have a given size, but I have an "enlarge" button to make them take the full space. The button simply toggles a CSS class to do that. However, doing this does **not** trigger a resize event, and so does not trigger a reflow. So I have the same problem of charts not filling their container.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/swaek268/3/

Again, I have found a way around the problem, but it feels like an even bigger hack.

```
var width = 0;
var planreflow = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      if(width!==$('#container').width()){
          $('#container').highcharts().reflow(); 
          console.log('reflow!')
      }
      width = $('#container').width();
      planreflow();
  }, 10);
};
planreflow();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found solutions to both of my problems:

1. **Wrong size when chart finishes loading:**

The problem does not come from Highcharts, but from the timing when the chart is created. I directly called `.highcharts()` from the `link()` function of my Angular directive. The JS looking essentially like this:

```
app.directive('dynamicView', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      $(element).highcharts({...});
    },    
  };
});
```

As my element also has a `ng-if` directive depending on whether the tab is selected or not, I imagine that when that condition turns `true`, angular calls the `link()` function before the dimension of the element is determined (I guess the HTML has to be ready in order to determine the size of the elements). So I think the problem was that I was calling `.highcharts()` before the document was ready. For some reason that I still don't understand, the size of the element is correct the first time ng-if turns true, but incorrect the next times.

Anyway, a solution (still not very elegant - but better than calling `reflow()`) is to delay the call to `.highcharts()` itself, to make sure that the HTML is ready when creating the charts:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
  setTimeout(function () {
    $(element).highcharts({...});
  }, 0);
}
```

Thank you *@Pavel Fus* for your comments on the behaviour of `.highcharts()` and `setTimeout()`.

2. **Chart not resizing when toggling a class**

For this problem I took advantage of Angular's eventing system.

In my controller controlling the full-screen button:

```
$scope.toggleFullScreen = function(e){
  $scope.$broadcast('fullscreen');
}
```

This event is passed down the hierarchy, ending-up to my directives containing the charts. All I have to do, when creating my charts is to listen to this event, and trigger a `reflow()` accordingly:

```
scope.$on('fullscreen', function(){
  setTimeout(function () { 
    $(element).highcharts().reflow(); 
  }, 0);
});
```

Note that --again-- the trick only works if I delay the reflow with `setTimeout()`. Not sure why.

I hope this helps! Spent quite a bit of time on this...

Comment: can you please see my question maybe you have an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Answer (score 1):

So, in fact you have two questions:

1) Incorrect size at second click. This is most probably caused by wrong width and height for a hidden (`display: none`) container. In that case, browsers report incorrect width/height (like `0px`). The same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436666/highcharts-issue-about-full-chart-width/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using/).

2) Setting class for a container wouldn't fire `resize` (or rather `reflow`) event for a chart. That mean you need to call `chart.reflow()` on your own. I suggest to do that in the same place as you change your class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that will not work for me:
1) My implementation of tabs is not using `display: none`. I'm using the angular directive `ng-if`, which means the content of the tab is re-generated entirely on each click. So the problem somehow has to come from some kind of persistent/state-full behaviour of Highcharts. In other words, using `.highcharts()` does not produce exactly the same result every time.

Comment: 2) As mentionned in my Fiddle, I can't do that, because where I change the class I don't know a priori the content of the container. It could be a chart, but it could also be a table, or text, or any kind of jquery-plugin-generated content. So I don't have a handle on `chart` to call `chart.reflow()`.

Comment: 1) `.highcharts()` produces the same output. If width/height is incorrect then  Highcharts uses default width/height. 2) You say you don't know, but you can call `planreflow()`? Anyway, can't you simply use: `if($("#container").highcharts()) { ... }`?

Comment: 1) If that's unquestionably the case, then I guess it's my angular directive that somehow behaves state-fully... There's a lot of code, so it's hard to share, unfortunately. 2) I can call `planreflow()` in the code that calls `.highchart()`, but the fullscreen-button does not know about this part of the code, nor about Highcharts. Could be potentially anything...

Comment: Also: 1) If the width/height *is* incorrect, then why does my hack (queuing the reflow) fixes the problem? `setTimeout(function () { chart.reflow(); }, 0);`

Comment: `setTimeout` creates new thread, and put on a stack - it's not 0ms, but rather a couple of ms delay. In other words, it allows browser to do some page reflows/redraws (non-js things) and most probably dimensions are proper at that point. Could you check your charts widths/heights? If those are 600x400 - then that are default values for width and height, when height/width is NaN/0.